# Django Model Objects Filter - Multiple keywords

Tags: django, django-models

Can you filter a model object like this?

Foo.objects.filter(name="This, That, Those")

So filtering all the objects that has those names; it would return all the objects with the names This, that and those.

If I know it was lets say only 3 keywords it would be easy to use OR or AND. But in my case there could be 1 or many more keywords

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Foo.objects.filter(name__in=["This", "That", "Those"])
```